# linux/wine/python-os parameter to ignore errors

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-14.04, wine, python-os

I am running wine on Ubuntu 14 to execute a windows application on multiple files from the shell. From the 3000 files, about 4 or 5 fail and raise a pop up error which stops the loop. Then I need to press OK in order for the loop to continue. Is there any parameter in wine, (or some shell command in linux) to ignore errors?
I would like the loop to continue without me having to be there to press OK.

EDIT:

I am running the loop in python and using `os` module to execute the command in the shell so if there's anything I can do from the Python side using `os` that would work too.

Comment: What exactly is wine doing that python couldn't do on its own?

Comment: What errors? Python errors? Wine errors? Linux errors? It's difficult to offer any meaningful advice if you don't know what the question is ;-) Also, why are you using wine with Python? That seems like a strange thing to do...

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarification. the windows app is converting some xml files to csvs. I know this can be done with Python in other ways but we are using the windows app for a special reason. I believe the errors are wine errors because when executing this on a windows, there are no errors. If anybody is interested, this is the converter which relies on .NET to function: https://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/releases/view/118938

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I am using python to loop through many files while executing a wine command that runs the windows app on each one of them

Comment: why the downvote? I am only asking if there is a way to ignore popup errors from wine, linux, or python os module...

Comment: found this solution: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_disable_the_GUI_crash_dialog.3F will see if it works later

Comment: forgot to mention this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps in the following link solved my issue! https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_disable_the_GUI_crash_dialog.3F